Copyright on song first performed in public
[Minor spoiler for the latest "Emily in Paris" episode.]
In the Netflix show "Emily in Paris", Emily's singer-songwriter friend Mindy has an idea for a song while the two of them are walking down a street. She takes over the piano of a nearby busker, and asks Emily to record her singing the song so she won't forget the words.
Naturally a crowd forms, and one of them also records her. Later he posts it to TikTok. Does he have the right to do this? Does the songwriter not have copyright protection because she didn't "fix" it in tangible form (e.g. writing the lyrics or music on paper or a computer file) before performing it?
In the episode, Mindy got a job on a TV show when the producers saw the video, so she's not likely to complain at that moment. But I can imagine licensing disputes down the road.
This happens in Rome if the jurisdiction matters.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Italian copyright law protects works regardless of whether they have been "fixed" (a condition that the Berne convention permits its signatories to impose but does not require).  In addition to this, EU directive 2001/29/EC requires member states to grant performers "the exclusive right to authorise or prohibit direct or indirect, temporary or permanent reproduction by any means and in any form, in whole or in part ... of fixations of their performances."
Therefore, the crowd member's posting of the video without the performer's permission was an infringement of her rights both as a performer and as the author of the musical work.
Even in a jurisdiction such as the United States that requires fixation as a condition for the existence of copyright, the copyright accrues to the author of the work, not to the person who fixed the work.  Had this event occurred in the US, the crowd member's recording the songwriter's performance would have caused the songwriter's copyright in the song to come into being, and the subsequent posting of the video would still have been an infringement.  At least, this is the natural conclusion from the literal provisions of the statute; I do not know whether courts have interpreted it differently.  The statute, 17 USC 102, says

(a) Copyright protection subsists, in accordance with this title, in original works of authorship fixed in any tangible medium of expression, now known or later developed, from which they can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device. Works of authorship include the following categories:
...
(2) musical works, including any accompanying words;

Beyond the requirement to be in a "tangible medium," there is no limitation on the circumstances of the fixation.

Under 17 USC 1101, this would be (equivalent to) an infringement in the US (it is as if Congress foresaw this exact scenario and wrote it out in the statute book). That law also extends to "trafficking" in such recordings even if they were made outside the US.

The fact that it was in a public space, does nothing to allow the onlookers to record it? Here I mean not for them to have ownership of the song, but just to record it and post it on social media. Interactions are regularly recorded and posted online when they happen in a public space. If that was forbidden, could I publicly preach and debate people on the street, and then sue people who have recorded me?

Recording is one thing, but posting on social media is copying.

@vsz whether the act of recording is lawful is a separate matter from whether it is copyright infringement to distribute the recording.  I understand that in Germany, it is indeed unlawful to record someone in public without permission.  In most US states, a person performing in public has a significantly reduced "reasonable expectation of privacy" and so making a recording of that person's performance would be lawful unless doing so exceeded the scope of fair use.  I don't know what Italian law has to say on the question.

@phoog In Germany: 1) Right of panorama does not apply to non-permanent installations 2) right of one's own image prevents publication but not recording 3) however, case-by-case, one may be charged for recording someone specifically in public spaces (if it borders on harassment, stalking, etc), 4) one may have the right to exert appropriate self defense due to violation of one's rights (right of one's own image, the photographer refusing to delete pics and continuing to take more).

@gnasher729 Bingo. I would add "for personal use" to "recording" but that is a quibble, and it is implied in your distinction.

@Wastrel: Note that the US law does not distinguish between those cases. Even the initial recording is unlawful, regardless of what you subsequently do with it (subsequent actions can give rise to additional liability, but you're still liable just for recording and doing nothing else). Of course, good luck tracking someone down and suing them in that case.

Most music, audiobooks etc are “fixated” by a sound engineer. And a book author who is not good at typing might dictate the text to their secretary. Sound engineer and secretary don’t hold the copyright.

@Kevin the recording is not unlawful if it falls under fair use, and the intended disposition of the recording is a major consideration in the fair use determination.

@gnasher729 I've lost track: has anyone (other than authors of deleted answers) said anything to suggest that sound engineers or secretaries would have an interest in a work that they had recorded or transcribed?

canada
I am answering based on the law that would apply if the scenario described were to happen in Canada.
The performer has the exclusive right to reproduce the fixation that was made without the performer's authorization.
The Rome Convention for the Protection of Performers, Producers of Phonograms and Broadcasting Organisations (1961) (Rome Convention), in  Article 7, envisages protection for performers that includes the possibility of preventing the reproduction, without their consent, of a fixation of their performance, where the original fixation itself was made without their consent (i.e. a bootleg of previously unrecorded material).
Canada is a signatory to the Rome Convention. So are Australia and Italy; the United States is not.
Part II of Canada's Copyright Act implements the protections for performers' performances, fulfilling Canada's obligations under the Rome Convention.
Sections 15, 24, and 26 give make the performer the first owner of "a copyright in the performer's performance" even where the first fixation is the unauthorized fixation.

"Performer has the exclusive right [...] without the performer's authorization"?

@infinitezero the performer has the exclusive right to reproduce the fixation.  The fixation was made without the performer's authorization

@phoog ah right. That makes sense.

If a performer on stage solicits ideas from audience members, and incorporates some of the ideas into the lyrics of an otherwise public-domain song, what would be the copyright status of the composite work?

@supercat if by "ideas" you mean specific lyrics, then the audience member is the author of those lyrics and holds the copyright. The performer has a license to sing those lyrics. Since the rest of the song in this hypothetical is in the public domain, the only author's rights are those in the new lyrics. Performer's rights in any recording of the performance belong to the performer, but the audience member's rights also cover the recordings. If by "idea" you mean something like a suggestion for a topic, then the author is the performer and the audience member has no copyright.
